# What does orthogonal eigenvectors mean?

Tags: matrices

What does it mean when one says "two eigenvectors are orthogonal"? How do you know if they are orthogonal?
When does two columns of a matrix become orthogonal?

Comment: Orthogonal means perpendicular, which means the inner product of the two vectors is zero.

Comment: We prefer to say orthogonal in linear algebra, and use words like inner product, since our vectors aren’t always geometric objects

Comment: It is important to know that two eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal is the matrix is **symmetric** (with real entries and distinct eigenvalues), which is a very current situation.